# To start Android Applications from website

Tags: html, android

I am a c# programmer that loves android phones knowing that I am never going to learn Java.
What I want to to is an ordinary website that starts the relevant applications from my android phone (Legend) with parameters like:

This works:
Mail - this opens the email klient with correct to=john@doe.com
href="tel:+4512345678" opens the phone with the correct digits on the screen
href="geo:something" opens google map and show you your location

This does not work:
href="sms:+4512345678, body=Hello You"
href="geo:+address" - I want to enten an adress I can navigate to...

Is the last ones possible do do or something like it? 
Can you send me link or description
Help would be very appreciated
Thanks in advance
/Bo

Comment: @BO M: Hai BO M, what you want to do, you want to impment an email and sms functionalities in urapplication. am i right?

Comment: Hi - Yes, i want to implement email, phone, sms and navigation

Answer (score 1):

Never say never. Java is pretty close to c#.

About your problem - check the [WTAI specs](http://mobile.kaywa.com/files/WAP-170-WTAI-20000707-a.pdf).

call number

```
<a href="wtai://wp/mc;PHONE_NUMBER">
```

send sms:

```
<a href="sms:PHONE_NUMBER?body=MESSAGE_BODY">
```

open maps with given geopoint:

```
<a href="geopoint:latitude,longitude">
```

open gtalk:

```
<a href="gtalk:ACTION?jid=USERNAME&from_jid=YOURNAME">
```